# How to correct error where 2 out of 3 users on chrooted network cannot gain write access?

Tags: debian, permissions, chroot, sftp

I have an SFTP server running on Debian. The directory is chrooted and is set up with privileges as such:

```
/sftp/+---testagent2----writespace
 750  |      755           755
      +---testagent3----writespace
      |      755           755 
      +---testagent4----writespace
             755           755
```

All agents can log in without issues. The problem is only `testagent2` can write within his `writespace`, the rest cannot, even though `testagent3` and `testagent4` can still download files.

I have experimented with various permission settings, such as `750`,`755`,`775`, and `777` but it doesn't make a difference. How can I correct this error?

Comment: Who owns the directories?

Comment: That was the answer! The owners never had ownership of `*/writespace`. I am now able to write to those directories with each respected user. Are you able to turn this into an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the 755 permissions, make sure that the appropriate users own their respective writespaces!